# Does the Greek word anēr mean man (adult male) or male (male of any age)?

Tags: greek, acts, lexicon

Bible verse

> 14 And increasingly believers in the Lord, large numbers of **men (ἀνήρ, G435)** and women, were being added to their number, (Acts 5:14, NASB20)

([Greek word study for anēr [ἀνήρ, G435]](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g435/nasb20/mgnt/0-1))

The best Greek dictionaries define anēr (ἀνήρ - G435) as a man (an adult male human being).

**New International Dictionary of New Testament Theology and Exegesis (NIDNTTE)**

> ἀνήρ G467 (aner), man, husband; άνδρίζομαι G437 (andrizomai), to behave in a manly way, be courageous.

**Theological Dictionary of the New Testament (TDNT)**

> The word is common as the general designation of a man with adjectives and substantives denoting the function, e.g., ἀνὴρ μάντις, but also ἄνδρες λῃσταί.

**A Greek-English Lexicon of the New Testament and Other Early Christian Literature (BDAG)**

> ἀνήρ, ά,νδρός, ό (Hom.+, common in all the mngs. known to our lit. and LXX) man.

**Strong's Greek Dictionary**

> ἀνήρ anḗr, an'-ayr; a primary word (compare G444); a man (properly as an individual male):—fellow, husband, man, sir.

Others however seem to include males of any age (men and boys).

**Bill Mounce Greek Dictionary**

> Gloss: man, male, husband; usually an adult male, but in some contexts the emphasis is on maturity rather than gender

**Thayer's Greek Lexicon**

> ἀνήρ, ἀνδρός, ὁ, a man, Latin vir. The meanings of this word in the N.
> T. differ in no respect from classic usage; for it is employed
>
> 1. with a reference to sex, and so to distinguish a man from a woman; either
>
> - a. as a male
> - b. as a husband
>
> 2. with a reference to age, and to distinguish an adult man from a boy.
> 3. universally, any male person, a man
> 4. when persons of either sex are included, but named after the more important.

Which is an accurate definition of anēr (ἀνήρ, G435): **man** (adult male) or **male** (male of any age)?

Comment: What is anyone going to add to these recognized and authoritative lexicons?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the questioner has answered his own question.

Comment: _Aner_ is an identifiable male person. _Anthropos_ is humanity. _Arsen_ is a male person, identified as male, specifically. _Arrhen_ is a 'solitary' male, that is to say a batchelor.

Comment: @Dottard No, I have not answered my question. Please, elaborate on what made you think I did. Thank you.

Comment: @NigelJ Please, explain what you mean by identifiable. Thank you.

Comment: If an individual (man) can be identified : named or described in such a manner that a single person is in view, rather than a group of individuals who share qualities. It would help if we knew why you were seeking this information. At the moment I am not clear as to what is behind the question.

Comment: @NigelJ In the passage above (Acts 5:14), it is a group of men that is not identifiable that was baptized and converted to Christianity. NASB20 translated Aner as Men, not Males. I would like to know if this is an accurate translation, implying adults only, or if the word Men (Aner) could include male children as well. Thank you.

Comment: So, I take it that you are trying to prove paedo-baptism by this analysis. The men were _baptised_ and so _were_ all identifiable as their names would be recorded and registered and they would be admitted to Church fellowship. That is why _aner_ is used and not _anthropos_.

Comment: I do not know what you are asking, unless you have an unstated agenda.  What extra meaning doi you want beyond a good lexicon?

Comment: @NigelJ Yes I am, you nailed it. Excellent explanation about Identifiable which makes complete sense to me now, as to why Aner was used as opposed to Anthropos.

Comment: @NigelJ Why do you think did Luke not use Arsen instead of Aner, is it for the same reason why Anthropos was not used?

Comment: _Arsen_ draws attention to the maleness of a man, as I understand the Greek meaning. I don't see why that would be relevant in the matter of baptism since  both males and males and females are baptised. So, no.

Comment: @Dottard I don't understand what you don't understand to justify closing the question. What do you mean by "unstated agenda"? This is a strange way to characterize a hermeneutical question and is confusing. Do you mean what led me to ask the question? I answered this in my comment above. Also, I am asking why some Greek lexicons have different definitions over the word Aner. How is that flagged "off-topic" and the question now Closed?

Comment: @NigelJ Good point about Arsen, thank you. Then, I don't know what else to think of Bill Mounce (which is actually based on the "A Greek-English Lexicon To The New Testament" by William Greenfield I believe) and Thayer lexicons defining Aner not only as Man but also as Male except perhaps due to a lesser quality Greek word definition. Could you recommend other Greek lexicons? Also, may I ask which one you are using? Thank you very much.

Comment: I cannot refer to any lexicon. One must be careful for sometimes the pure water of truth is contaminated at the very source by bias introduced by worldly or heretical lexicographers. What I _can_ do is guide you to my studies . . . .  [The Son of man : pp 6-13](https://belmontpublications.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/10A-The-Son-of-man.pdf) Regards, Nigel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a text meant to include a baby, it could have used the Greek word *'brephos'*.

If a text wanted to specify a young man, even a youngster, it could have used the Greek word *'neaniskos'*.

If a text wanted to specify a man, a husband, it would use *'aner'*.

This is from *Young's Analytical Concordance*.

So, **where there is no extra qualification as to the age of the male (i.e a baby or a youngster or a young man), the term *'aner'* should be understood as a man, a husband.** (That would not rule out a mature man who was a widower, of course, or a mature man who had never married. It's just that, in those days, mature men were usually married, as opposed to young men who usually were not.)

To identify a male of a different age to that of a mature, marriageable-age male, there were other Greek words that would have been used.

**EDIT:**  In view of the OPs comment to me, a search through Young’s Concondance reveals these further details as to whether *aner* in the N.T. ever means a child, an adolescent etc.

Out of 160 instances of *aner* being used, there is not even one instance of it allowing for inclusion of a child or an adolescent. Indeed, in Matthew 14:21 & 15:38, the writer is clear in distinguishing between the many adult males present, and the children present. The children come under the Greek for a little, or young child, or youth – *paidion / pais*. “From boyhood” is *paidiothen*.

An interesting verse is Revelation 12:5 where *arrhen*, denoting a male, is used for the visionary woman bringing forth “a man child” – symbolically ‘birthing’ this male baby; a baby at the moment of birth.

The reasonable view is that every time *aner* is used, it speaks of a male of mature years, as opposed to a baby, a child, or a youth. When such a youngster is meant, there are Greek words to make that clear.

Comment: When Thayer or Bill Mounce says (above) Aner could mean Male, should we understand this as a male of any age or do they imply an adult male? Do we have examples in the NT or Ancient Greek manuscripts where Aner was used for a child/adolescent/minor/non-adult/non-marriageable age person?

Comment: @TruthSeeker  I have spent some time searching Young's Concordance to deal with your related question, and have added an edit with my findings. There should be no difference with Thayer and Mounce with what Young shows because they are all dealing with the same Greek words.

Comment: Thank you, Anne. I very much appreciate the time you spent researching this and the very interesting and relevant findings. Is it the "Young's Analytical Concordance to the Bible (1984) you are referring to? I am selecting your answer as the most helpful in finding my solution. Thank you again.

Comment: @TruthSeeker  Yes, it's Robert Young's Analytical Concordance. I have the 8th edition which was revised in 1939 (and my copy is the 1979 impression.) Many thanks.